# Evaluate $ \int_{0}^{\cos^2x} \arccos\sqrt{t} \,dt,$ and $ \int_{0}^x t\sin2t \,dt,$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Now, the problem is like this: 
We have the following functions :   $$ f_1 :R->R , f_1(x) =  \int_{0}^x t\sin(2t) \,dt,
f_2 :[0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \to R, f_2(x) = \int_{0}^{\cos^2x} \arccos\sqrt{t} \,dt,$$ 
It asks to calculate $f_1(x) +f_2(x)$ for all the values of x from the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

My attempt was to calculate both of the integrals. I've started with $f_2(x)$  :$\displaystyle \arccos\sqrt x=u\implies \sqrt x=\cos u\implies x=\cos^2u\implies dx=-2\sin u\cos u\ du=-\sin(2u)\ du$ but I am getting stuck . Could you help me out ?

Comment: I don't see how you are stuck. You now have $\mathrm{d}t$ so you can perform the substitution in $f_2(x)$ giving$$f_2(x)=-\int_{\pi/2}^xu\sin{(2u)}\mathrm{d}u$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $t=\cos^2(u)$ reveals

$$\int_0^{\cos^2(x)}\arccos(\sqrt t)\,dt=-\int_{\pi/2}^x u\sin(2u)\,du$$

for $x\in [0,\pi/2]$

Can you finish now?